# mismatch value for same variable in conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using conditional rendering to decide if an element is visible or not (`hello` in this case). However, I found that the condition (`added`) is true when is printed in the console, but `hello` doesn't show up.
Here is my code in the `render()` of the component.

```
  render() {
    let {added}=this.state;
    console.log(added);
    return <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
      {added==true && <h1>hello</h1>}
    </div>;
  }
```

Thank you so much

A little bit of background: `added` is updated by the component's child. I think it's updated successfully since console prints the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

change logic like this, use of `&&` will make sure its true and then go for other `<h1>` tag to render, else if false then not render it

```
  render() {
    let {added}=this.state;
    console.log(added);
    return <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
      {added && <h1>hello</h1>}
    </div>;
  }
```

if you want to use ternary conditions operator `? :`, do like this syntax,

```
{added == true ? <h1>hello</h1> : null}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's still not working. I tried to show the ```added``` on page by ```<p>{added}</p>``` but nothing shows up. I guess I miss some important features of component render:(